# conditional php inside haml class name

Tags: php, haml

I'm trying to have a conditional statement in haml for the class name. In regular html I would do.

```
<a href="/" class=linkHeader<?php if($self) { echo ' active'; } ?></a>
```

How would I do this in haml?

```
%a{:class=>"linkHeader", :href => "/"}
```

Comment: Don't know haml but what about passing the complete classname from PHP to haml?

Answer (score 1):

What are you using ? MtHaml ? The old (and broken) phamlp ?

I'm using this on MtHaml :

```
%a.linkHeader{class: $self ? 'active' : ''}
```

Comment: I'm using phamlp, is that not recommended?

Comment: Phamlp is very buggy, old (2010) and may not be able to parse. On the other hand, MtHaml is new,shiny, totally tested in-depth (much more than phamlp), can parse cases like `a(c=foo(1,2))` and even interface with Twig! I definitely recommend it.